# Why are many shower hoses "explosion proof"?

Tags: shower, water-pressure, hose

I noticed that many shower hoses are advertised as "explosion proof". Since I have never seen a shower head with a tap on it, I'd think the hose has to withstand only a fraction of the pressure that the regular plumbing would be required to withstand. Off course it has to be allot more flexible, but "explosion proof" seems to me quite an exaggeration.

Even if a shower head clogs up to the extent that the pipe would burst, it would not be called an explosion would it? My guess is that this is a marketing thing that has been copied by different brands and merely means that the pipe will not bust in the way a balloon would.

Is there any rational reason or circumstance where one should prefer an "explosion proof" hose instead of one that has no mention on the package of being "explosion proof"?

Comment: Many handheld shower heads include a valve to let you shut off the flow of water (i.e. [Delta Full Spray Push Button Hand Shower](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000H5YEWS/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_3)), so the hose often needs to withstand full household water pressure. I've never had one burst on me, but it seems like it would be more of an annoyance than an explosive danger.

Comment: @Johnny agreed: you could waste a LOT of water if the hose burst when nobody was home, let alone the damage that could be done if the water sprayed out of the shower enclosure.

Comment: @Johnny, I've never seen one like that before. I guess using it would require a check valve before the main mixing tap to prevent the hot water from flowing into the cold supply pipe. There is also a possibility that they are banned from the market here in Holland (all kinds of safety regulations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing the result of poorly-translated product descriptions from China and elsewhere. For example:

> Advantages: Withdrawing life greatly improved. Should not damage the leaking. The inner tube using the nylon braided package EPDM more resistant wound.

[Honory99 1.5m Pull-type Copper Core Explosion-proof Shower Hose](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VTAL8VK)

This product would probably be called "burst-resistant" or something similar if described by a native English speaker.

[ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)

Comment: I guess you are probably correct. The first one I encountered was [this one](http://www.banggood.com/KCASA-1_2m-PVC-Explosion-proof-Bathroom-Shower-Hose-Anti-wrap-Waterpipe-High-Temperature-Resistance-p-1054168.html). Funny I did not notice the bad english until you pointed it out. After searching for "explosion proof shower hose" I found many others, and got a totally wrong impression.

Comment: IDC what you call it; *it will be **"braided"***, otherwise it isn't.